# g++ output not properly aligned in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, format, g++, alignment

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Terminal: Bash shell

Compiler: g++

I am compiling a program using this command "g++ rvalue.cpp -o rvalue.o", I am getting this formatting if there is compile error in the programs.

[image]

I have even tried with g++-6, this seems some problem in bash settings which I am not aware of. Please let me know if there is such settings which can fix this problem.

Note: I am not asking how to resolve error but why output is not aligned properly.

---

Tarun Chawla

Comment: 1) What is the expected alignment? 2) Why are all the names missing from the output? 3) Does it work if you start a new shell (`dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc), *then* run the `g++` command?

Comment: I am not sure about exact alignment but I expect error to be followed by proper line number indicating appropriate symbols. Not sure why symbols are missing. I checked with dash and same problem is observed.

Comment: Can you try without any bash settings, e.g. `env -i bash --norc -c 'g++ rvalue.cpp -o rvalue.o'` ?

Comment: I got it, seems problem with color scheme. I just copied the contents of shell to a text file and everything was fine so I changed the color scheme with yellow background assuming that text which is missing in output has black color too due to which problem is seen and bingo I was correct.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for your help.

Comment: Thanks @thatotherguy for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that blank spaces in the above image has text but color is black and terminal background color is black too due to which we are not able to see the required text which let me to assume that text is not properly aligned but it seems text was there but subsumed in background as color of text was same as background. You can verify this problem by copying the content of shell to a text file and see if everything looks ok.

Problem can be resolved by choosing any other appropriate color scheme.